# Label for checkbox in Angular

Tags: html, angular

In a regular HTML file we can do as in html to have a privilege to check the checkbox by clicking anywhere on label, even by setting the checkbox input display to  none

```
 <label for="check">
   <input id="check"  type="checkbox">
 </label>
```

Why same is not working in Angular? 
I'm interested how I can do same in Angular 5+.

Comment: Its same for the angular 5 too, did you tried?

Comment: Yes i tried but it didn't work. Actually I want to apply some styling when it is checked and don't want to use .ts for that but it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

It works in Angular as well.

Sample code

```
<label for="check"> Click here
   <input id="check" [(ngModel)]="hello" [hidden]="true"  type="checkbox">
 </label>
```

Demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ncjng

Comment: I don't need a function, the only thing that I need is to make it checked so to trigger CSS style.

Comment: Yeah, the example given is not using any function.

Comment: In my case it is not working, I make [hidden]="false" and when I click on area of label, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Need to check what you have done exactly, it will be easier if you can create a sample in stackblitz.